# load multiple views on my route but i could load one view only with return view();

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am using codeigniter 4  and I want to load multiple views on my route but I could load one view only with `return view();`
`$this-load->view();` **function is not working..** 
I am able to load only one view with return view(); please help me with this.
**My controller - Home.php :**

```
// in index only return view()  works
    public function index()
        {   $data['page_title'] = 'Your title';
            return view('welcome_message');
           // $this->load->view('header');
            //$this->load->view('welcome_message');
            //$this->load->view('footer');
        }
    //the views in homepge function are not loaded
        public function homePage()
        {
            $data['page_title'] = 'Your title';
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
```

**Route.php**

```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('dash', 'Home::homePage');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeigniter 4 does not have a $this->load->view function. That was the old way of loading views in codeigniter 3.

When you're using codeigniter 4 you need to use the view() function to load views. There's two ways you can do that. You can either return it or echo it.

If its just one view my advise is to return it like you're doing in your first example. But if its more than one you need to echo them in order.

Something like this:

```
    public function index()
    {   
       $data['page_title'] = 'Your title'; 
       echo view('header');
       echo view('welcome_message');
       echo view('footer');
    }
```

Comment: it works.... thank you. I have been using codeigniter 3 for long time and just switched to codeigniter 4. and using 3's method t load the view