# CodeIgniter 4: Pass $data to the View file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Can someone help me with this? I can't figure out on how can I show the results on the View file. I tried using `$this->load->view('list-logs',$data);` but it shows the error `Call to a member function view() on null`.

CONTROLLER

```
public function getLogs()
    {
        helper(['form']);

        $EstMod = new EstMod();
        $data['est_data'] = $EstMod->orderBy('e_id', 'DESC')->findAll();

        $rep_est = $this->request->getPost('rep_est');
        $rep_date = $this->request->getPost('rep_date');

        $builder = $this->db->table("logs as l");
            $builder->select('l.l_id, u.fname, u.mname, u.lname, u.dept, u.user_type, u.u_grdsec, e.e_name, l.date_added, DATE(l.date_added), date_format(l.date_added, "%H:%i") as "time"');
            $builder->join('users as u', 'l.u_id = u.u_id');
            $builder->join('establishment as e', 'l.e_id = e.e_id');
            $builder->where('DATE(l.date_added)', $rep_date);
            $builder->groupBy('date_format(l.date_added, "%H:%i"), l.u_id');
            $data['logs_data'] = $builder->get()->getResult();

        $this->load->view('list-logs',$data);
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($data);

    }
```

VIEW

```
<?php


if ($logs_data) {
    foreach ($logs_data as $row) {
        
        echo '
        <tr>
          <td>' . $row['date_added'] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row['lname'] . ", " . $row['fname'] . ", " . $row['mname'] . '</td>';
        
        if ($row['user_type'] == 'S') {
            echo '<td>STUDENT</td>';
        } else if ($row['user_type'] == 'E') {
            echo '<td>EMPLOYEE</td>';
        } else if ($row['user_type'] == 'P') {
            echo '<td>VISITOR</td>';
        }
        
        if ($row['dept'] == 'GS') {
            echo '<td>GRADE SCHOOL</td>';
        } else if ($row['dept'] == 'JHS') {
            echo '<td>JUNIOR HIGH SCHOOL</td>';
        } else if ($row['dept'] == 'SHS') {
            echo '<td>SENIOR HIGH SCHOOL</td>';
        }
        
        echo '</td>
        <td>' . $row['u_grdsec'] . '</td>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This could probably find a duplicate but if you're actually in CI4, then call view(). The way you're doing it now is from CI3. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=view#view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [load multiple views on my route but i could load one view only with return view();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949518/load-multiple-views-on-my-route-but-i-could-load-one-view-only-with-return-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use CodeIgniter 4 then you must call the view ont controller like this:

```
echo view('my_view', $data)
```